# Angularjs WebApi is not working in Asp.net MVC Entity Framework

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

> This error is Occur after running the web application. this is picture of inspect elements of google chrome.
>   [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUjpG.png)
>   [See Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qlxI.png)
>
> i want to us entity framework
>   here is class code... when i comment the 
>   public virtual List tblproduct { get; set; } and
>   public virtual List tblproduct { get; set; } this its working perfetcly how to completety use entity framework mvc in it

```
[Table("tblCatagory")]
    public class AddCatagory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [StringLength(56)]
        public string CataName { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Product> tblproduct { get; set; }
        //public virtual List<AddSubCatagory> tblsubcatagory { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("tblSubCatagory")]
    public class AddSubCatagory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [StringLength(56)]
        public string SubCataName { get; set; }
        public int AddCatagoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual AddCatagory tblcatagory { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Product> tblproduct { get; set; }
    }
```

> product class code

```
[Table("tblProduct")]
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [StringLength(56)]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(156)]
        public string ProductDes { get; set; }
        public int ProductQty { get; set; }
        public double ProductRate { get; set; }
        public double Inches { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int AddCatagoryId { get; set; }
        public int AddSubCatagoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual AddCatagory tblcatagory{ get; set; }
        public virtual AddSubCatagory tblsubcatagory{ get; set; }
    }
```

> wepapi controller

```
public List<Product> Getproducts()
        {
            var result = db.products.ToList();
            return result;
        }
```

> angularjs code..

```
GetAllPro();
 function GetAllPro() {
        $http.get("/api/Products").then(function (response) {
            $scope.Pro = response.data;
        }, function () {
            alert("Error")
            })
    }
```

Comment: Can you place a `try ... catch` around your GetProducts and check the exceptions thats thrown?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) this error is ocurr

Comment: `public List<Product> Getproducts()
    { try{
        var result = db.products.ToList();
        return result;} catch(Exception ex){ //BREAK HERE }}`

Comment: As @StefanKert wrote we need exception details (inner exception also)

Comment: public ProductsController()
        {

            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }                    my problem is solve by adding this thanks programmers for your response...